# Janus Grid .NET C# Make cell edit by user

Tags: c#, winforms, janus

I have a problem with Janus Grid. I am trying to make cell of the one column to be edit so user can change value in particular cell.
I try:

`this.myJanusGrid.RootTable.Columns[0].EditType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditType.TextBox`

and

`this.myJanusGrid.RootTable.Columns[0].Selectable=true`

None of these two attempt were successful.

Thank's in advance for any help and suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
this.myJanusGrid.RootTable.AllowEdit =  Janus.Web.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.True;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more columns that you don´t want them to be editable, in adittion you should do a column bucle and mark each column you don´t want to be editable this way (VB):

```
For Each column As GridEXColumn In myJanusGrid.RootTable.Columns
  If column.Key.ToUpper() <> "EDITABLE_COLUMN_NAME" Then
     column.SelectableCells = SelectableCells.None
  End If
Next
```